# Find sequences of numbers, in the fastest way on mysql,

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one billion lines. Each line is a sequence of numbers:

```
32098;1278;23902;8469
42710;17864;32230
230984;812918;420322;182972
339028;232329;2190120;23302;182972
232329;17864;32230;23302;182972
```

How to store that data and search in it, so the search time is minimal to find any sub sequences:

Example: searching for sequence "17864;32230" outputs:

```
42710;17864;32230
232329;17864;32230;23302;182972
```

What i have tried:

- storing lines in varchar (ascii), and searching: like "%17864;32230%"  => very slow...
- storing lines in varchar (ascii), will fulltext index and searching: against(' "17864;32230" ' in boolean mode)  => faster...
- storing lines in varchar (ascii), will fulltext index and searching: against(' +17864 +32230' in boolean mode) and line like "%17864;32230%"  => fastest i found...

Any faster method ?

Comment: MySQL does not have an "array" type, so I don't understand your data representation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, allright, i edit: array of numbers => sequence of numbers

Comment: *searching for sequence "17864;32230" outputs* Does the next two values will be selected: "17864;123456;32230", "123456;32230;17864" ?

Comment: *How to store that data and search in it, so the search time is minimal to find any sub sequences:* - normalize to "one value in a field of numeric type, a lot of records per source record".

Comment: @akina,  "17864;123456;32230", "123456;32230;17864" must not be outputs, because they do not contain the sequence "17864;32230"

Comment: I.e. your sequence is positionally-dependent... well. Does the sequence to be found is always 2-valued, or its length (in elements) may vary?

Comment: @Akina,  sequence to be found is always 2-valued.  You are right :)

Comment: Does each separate value in "array" has some upper limit? not more that 6 digits, for example...

Comment: @Akina, you are right, in my specific case, numbers in sequence are limited to 8 digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *searching for sequence "17864;32230" outputs* Does the next two values will be selected: "17864;123456;32230", "123456;32230;17864" ? – Akina
>
> @akina, "17864;123456;32230", "123456;32230;17864" must not be outputs, because they do not contain the sequence "17864;32230" – JoJo
>
> I.e. your sequence is positionally-dependent... well. Does the sequence to be found is always 2-valued, or its length (in elements) may vary? – Akina
>
> @Akina, sequence to be found is always 2-valued. You are right :) – JoJo
>
> Does each separate value in "array" has some upper limit? not more that 6 digits, for example... – Akina
>
> @Akina, you are right, in my specific case, numbers in sequence are limited to 8 digits – JoJo 10 mins ago

Look for this solution:

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=263c5c69548e9e58fdab9c7af3fdf781)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sourcetable ( id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>                            dataarray TEXT );
> INSERT INTO sourcetable (dataarray) VALUES 
> ('32098;1278;23902;8469'),
> ('42710;17864;32230'),
> ('230984;812918;420322;182972'),
> ('339028;232329;2190120;23302;182972'),
> ('232329;17864;32230;23302;182972');
> ```

> ```
> -- create indexing table
> CREATE TABLE indexingtable ( id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>                              sequence BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>                              PRIMARY KEY (sequence, id) );
> -- and fill it
> INSERT IGNORE INTO indexingtable
> -- assume not more than 6 elements per "array"
> WITH cte AS ( SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 )
> SELECT id, CONCAT(LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dataarray, ';', num), ';', -1), 9, '0'),
>                   LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dataarray, ';', num+1), ';', -1), 9, '0'))
> FROM sourcetable, cte;
> ```

> ```
> -- search for "17864;32230"
> SET @criteria := 17864000032230;
>
> -- perform searching
> SELECT sourcetable.*
> FROM sourcetable
> JOIN indexingtable USING (id)
> WHERE sequence = @criteria;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | dataarray                      
> -: | :------------------------------
>  2 | 42710;17864;32230              
>  5 | 232329;17864;32230;23302;182972
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN 
> SELECT sourcetable.*
> FROM sourcetable
> JOIN indexingtable USING (id)
> WHERE sequence = @criteria;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type | table         | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                          | rows | filtered | Extra                   
> -: | :---------- | :------------ | :--------- | :----- | :------------ | :------ | :------ | :------------------------------------------- | ---: | -------: | :-----------------------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | indexingtable | null       | ref    | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | const                                        |    2 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index
>  1 | SIMPLE      | sourcetable   | null       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | fiddle_KJQBRBTPCZAIOJRJHGJJ.indexingtable.id |    1 |   100.00 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=263c5c69548e9e58fdab9c7af3fdf781)*

---

The `indexingtable` create by the query will be extremely long and expensive process on a billion source records. I'd recommend to export source data to text (SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE), convert it using any script/progrmming language, then import into the `indexingtable`. It will be also long, but much faster than by the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rebuild the data, you could do the following.

Structure the data vertically -- you'll have billions of rows:

```
id     n      val
1      1      32098
1      2      1278
1      3      23902
1      4      8469
2      1      42710
2      2      17864
2      3      32230
```

With another table:

```
id     sequence
1      32098;1278;23902;8469
2      42710;17864;32230
```

Then you can try:

```
select ta.id
from table1 ta join
     table1 tb
     on tb.id = ta.id and
        tb.n = ta.n + 1 and
        tb.val = 32230
where ta.val = 17864
```

For this you want indexes on `(id, n, val)` and `(val, id, n)`.

I would expect this to be fairly competitive with the full-text search method.  I'm actually surprised that option (3) is faster than option (2).

The advantage is that it might give you more flexibility on the types of sequences that you are looking for.

Comment: "bilion of records" and `tb.n = ta.n + 1`?

Comment: Great idea @GordonLinoff !, i am going to try and give results.  Edit suggestions: "table1 tb" => "table2 tb"

Comment: @JoJo . . . No.  That is a self-join.